# numpy.shape gives inconsistent responses - why?

Tags: python, numpy

Why does the program

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([1,2])
print(c.shape)
d = np.array([[1],[2]]).transpose()
print(d.shape)
```

give

```
(2,)
(1,2)
```

as its output? Shouldn't it be

```
(1,2)
(1,2)
```

instead? I got this in both python 2.7.3 and python 3.2.3

Comment: Others might ask the other way round, so I think you should tell why you expect the later.

Comment: You may be thinking of matlab, but check the difference between `array` and `matrix`, in numpy, arrays are preferable.

Comment: @hakre I don't really see any difference (in real life) between a (horizontal) list and a 1 x n matrix, so I expected the shape of the plain array to be 1 x n - and I also expected d = [1, 2] and not [[1, 2]], but this has it's own sort of logic once you see what's going on.

Answer (score 18):

When you invoke the `.shape` attribute of a `ndarray`, you get a tuple with as many elements as dimensions of your array. The length, ie, the number of rows, is the first dimension (`shape[0]`)

- You start with an array : `c=np.array([1,2])`. That's a plain 1D array, so its shape will be a 1-element tuple, and `shape[0]` is the number of elements, so `c.shape = (2,)`
- Consider `c=np.array([[1,2]])`. That's a 2D array, with 1 row. The first and only row is `[1,2]`, that gives us two columns. Therefore, `c.shape=(1,2)` and `len(c)=1`
- Consider `c=np.array([[1,],[2,]])`. Another 2D array, with 2 rows, 1 column: `c.shape=(2,1)` and `len(c)=2`.
- Consider `d=np.array([[1,],[2,]]).transpose()`: this array is the same as `np.array([[1,2]])`, therefore its shape is `(1,2)`.

Another useful attribute is `.size`: that's the number of elements across all dimensions, and you have for an array `c` `c.size = np.product(c.shape)`.

More information on the shape in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-62ef2d3c0a5b4b7d6fdc48e4a60fe48b1ffe5006).

Comment: I don't really have a useful comment, but I feel the need to say...this kinda bugs me for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

`len(c.shape)` is the "depth" of the array.

For `c`, the array is just a list (a vector), the depth is 1.
For `d`, the array is a list of lists, the depth is 2.

Note:

```
c.transpose()
# array([1, 2])
```

which is not `d`, so this behaviour is not inconsistent.

```
dt = d.transpose()
# array([[1],
#        [2]])
dt.shape # (2,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick Fix: check the .ndim property - if its 2, then the .shape property will work as you expect.

Reason Why: if the .ndim property is 2, then numpy reports a shape value that agrees with the convention. If the .ndim property is 1, then numpy just reports shape in a different way.

More talking: When you pass np.array a lists of lists, the .shape property will agree with standard notions of the dimensions of a matrix: (rows, columns).

If you pass np.array just a list, then numpy doesn't think it has a matrix on its hands, and reports the shape in a different way.

The question is: does numpy think it has a matrix, or does it think it has something else on its hands.

Answer (score 0):

`transpose` does not change the number of dimensions of the array. If `c.ndim == 1`, `c.transpose() == c`. Try:

```
c = np.array([1,2])
print c.shape
print c.T.shape
c = np.atleast_2d(c)
print c.shape
print c.T.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Matlab, I also find it difficult that a single-dimensional array is not organized as (row_count, colum_count)

My function had to respond consistently on a single-dimensional ndarray like [x1, x2, x3] or a list of arrays [[x1, x2, x3], [x1, x2, x3], [x1, x2, x3]].

This worked for me:

```
dim = np.shape(subtract_matrix)[-1]
```

Picking the last dimension.