# nparray.T.reshape(x, -1).reshape(-1) : what does this do to the nparray?

Tags: python, numpy

With

```
>>> a.shape
(207, 155, 3)
```

What does this numpy code do to the numpy array a?

```
a = a.T.reshape(self.channels,-1).reshape(-1)
```

Comment: transposes and flattens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> a.shape
(207, 155, 3)
```

I'm going to suppose that `a` represents an image of size 155×207 pixels, with 3 colour channels per pixel:

```
>>> height, width, channels = a.shape
```

(Note that I'm assuming here that the *first* axis is vertical and the *second* axis is horizontal: see "[Multidimensional Array Indexing Order Issues](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues)" for an explanation.)

```
>>> b = a.T
>>> b.shape
(3, 155, 207)
```

`a.T` returns the transposed array. But actually under the hood it doesn't alter the image data in any way. A NumPy array has two parts: a *data buffer* containing the raw numerical data, and a *view* which describes how to index the data buffer. When you reshape or transpose an array, NumPy leaves the data buffer alone and creates a new view describing the new way to index the same data. ([See here for a longer explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074424/68063))

So `a` indexes the image using three axes (*y*, *x*, *c*), and `b` indexes the same image using the same three axes in the opposite order (*c*, *x*, *y*):

```
>>> x, y, c = 100, 200, 1
>>> a[y, x, c] == b[c, x, y]
True
```

The first call to [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
>>> c = b.reshape(3, -1)
>>> c.shape
(3, 32085)
```

flattens the last two indices into one (with the third index changing fastest), so that `c` indexes the image using two axes (*c*, *x* × height + *y*):

```
>>> a[y, x, c] == c[c, x * height + y]
True
```

The second reshape:

```
>>> d = c.reshape(-1)
>>> d.shape
(96255,)
```

flattens the remaining two indices into one, so that `d` indexes the image using the single axis ((*c* × width) + *x*) × height + *y*:

```
>>> a[y, x, c] == d[((c * width) + x) * height + y]
True
```

Note that the whole operation could be done in just one step using [`numpy.flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatten.html):

```
>>> (a.flatten(order='F') == d).all()
True
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation! well guessed, this is an image.