# Explaining the differences between dim, shape, rank, dimension and axis in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm new to python and numpy in general. I read several tutorials and still so confused between the differences in dim, ranks, shape, aixes and dimensions. My mind seems to be stuck at the matrix representation. So if you say that A is a matrix that looks like this:

```
A = 

1 2 3
4 5 6
```

then all I can think of is a 2x3 matrix (two rows and three columns). Here I understand that the shape is 2x3. But I really I am unable to go out side the thinking of a 2D matrices. I don't understand for example the [dot() documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) when it says "For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b". I'm so confused and unable to understand this. I don't understand like if V is a N:1 vector and M is N:N matrix, how dot(V,M) or dot(M,V) work and the difference between them.

Can anyone then please explain to me what is a N dimensional array, what's a shape, what's an axis and how does it relate to the documentation of the dot() function? It would be great if the explanation visualizes the ideas.

Comment: Are you familiar with matrix multiplication?

Comment: @unutbu sure! but if you do dot(V,M) and consider it as a matrix multiplication, then it's wrong because V is N:1 and M is N:N. But dot(M,V) is correct. However doing dot(V,M) still gives a result!!!

Comment: @AlexTwain that's impossible. see my answer, or show your code.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074424/68063) has an introduction to shapes.

Answer (score 14):

Dimensionality of NumPy arrays must be understood in the [data structures sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Multidimensional_arrays), not the mathematical sense, i.e. it's the number of scalar indices you need to obtain a scalar value.(*)

E.g., this is a 3-d array:

```
>>> X = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
>>> X
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

Indexing once gives a 2-d array (matrix):

```
>>> X[0]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Indexing twice gives a 1-d array (vector), and indexing three times gives a scalar.

The rank of `X` is its number of dimensions:

```
>>> X.ndim
3
>>> np.rank(X)
3
```

Axis is roughly synonymous with dimension; it's used in broadcasting operations:

```
>>> X.sum(axis=0)
array([[12, 14, 16, 18],
       [20, 22, 24, 26],
       [28, 30, 32, 34]])
>>> X.sum(axis=1)
array([[12, 15, 18, 21],
       [48, 51, 54, 57]])
>>> X.sum(axis=2)
array([[ 6, 22, 38],
       [54, 70, 86]])
```

To be honest, I find this definition of "rank" confusing since it matches neither the name of the attribute `ndim` nor the [linear algebra definition of rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29).

Now regarding `np.dot`, what you have to understand is that there are three ways to represent a vector in NumPy: 1-d array, a column vector of shape `(n, 1)` or a row vector of shape `(1, n)`. (Actually, there are more ways, e.g. as a `(1, n, 1)`-shaped array, but these are quite rare.) `np.dot` performs vector multiplication when both arguments are 1-d, matrix-vector multiplication when one argument is 1-d and the other is 2-d, and otherwise it performs a (generalized) matrix multiplication:

```
>>> A = np.random.randn(2, 3)
>>> v1d = np.random.randn(2)
>>> np.dot(v1d, A)
array([-0.29269547, -0.52215117,  0.478753  ])
>>> vrow = np.atleast_2d(v1d)
>>> np.dot(vrow, A)
array([[-0.29269547, -0.52215117,  0.478753  ]])
>>> vcol = vrow.T
>>> np.dot(vcol, A)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-36-98949c6de990>", line 1, in <module>
    np.dot(vcol, A)
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

The rule "sum product over the last axis of `a` and the second-to-last of `b`" matches and generalizes the common definition of matrix multiplication.

(*) Arrays of `dtype=object` are a bit of an exception, since they treat any Python object as a scalar.

Comment: I didn't understand the idea of the sum over the axies. How is it done? Can you elaborate on this more please?

Comment: @AlexTwain: it's easier to explain with matrices. Let `A = array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`. Then `A.sum(axis=0) == array([5, 7, 9])`, i.e. a sum over each column, while `A.sum(axis=1) == array([ 6, 15])`, a sum over each row.

Comment: `To be honest, I find this definition of "rank" confusing`  That's why `rank` was deprecated and replaced with `ndim`. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#rank-function

Answer (score 4):

`np.dot` is a generalization of matrix multiplication. 
In regular matrix multiplication, an (N,M)-shape matrix multiplied with a (M,P)-shaped matrix results in a (N,P)-shaped matrix. The resultant shape can be thought of as being formed by squashing the two shapes together (`(N,M,M,P)`) and then removing the middle numbers, `M` (to produce `(N,P)`). This is the property that `np.dot` preserves while generalizing to arrays of higher dimension.

When the docs say,

> "For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the
>   second-to-last of b".

it is speaking to this point. An array of shape `(u,v,M)` dotted with an array of shape `(w,x,y,M,z)` would result in an array of shape `(u,v,w,x,y,z)`.

---

Let's see how this rule looks when applied to

```
In [25]: V = np.arange(2); V
Out[25]: array([0, 1])

In [26]: M = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2); M
Out[26]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

First, the easy part:

```
In [27]: np.dot(M, V)
Out[27]: array([1, 3])
```

There is no surprise here; this is just matrix-vector multiplication.

Now consider

```
In [28]: np.dot(V, M)
Out[28]: array([2, 3])
```

Look at the shape of V and M:

```
In [29]: V.shape
Out[29]: (2,)

In [30]: M.shape
Out[30]: (2, 2)
```

So `np.dot(V,M)` is like matrix multiplication of a (2,)-shaped matrix with a (2,2)-shaped matrix, which should result in a (2,)-shaped matrix.

The last (and only) axis of `V` and the second-to-last axis of `M` (aka the first axis of `M`) are multiplied and summed over, leaving only the last axis of `M`.

If you want to visualize this: `np.dot(V, M)` looks as though V has 1 row and 2 columns:

```
[[0, 1]] * [[0, 1],
            [2, 3]]
```

and so, when V is multiplied by M, `np.dot(V, M)` equals

```
[[0*0 + 1*2],     [2, 
 [0*1 + 1*3]]   =  3]
```

However, I don't really recommend trying to visualize NumPy arrays this way -- at least I never do. I focus almost exclusively on the shape.

```
(2,) * (2,2)
   \   /
    \ /
    (2,)
```

You just think about the "middle" axes being dotted, and disappearing from the resultant shape.

---

`np.sum(arr, axis=0)` tells NumPy to sum the elements in `arr` *eliminating* the 0th axis. If `arr` is 2-dimensional, the 0th axis are the rows. So for example, if `arr` looks like this:

```
In [1]: arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3); arr
Out[1]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

then `np.sum(arr, axis=0)` will sum along the columns, thus *eliminating* the 0th axis (i.e. the rows).

```
In [2]: np.sum(arr, axis=0)
Out[2]: array([3, 5, 7])
```

The 3 is the result of 0+3, the 5 equals 1+4, the 7 equals 2+5.

Notice `arr` had shape (2,3), and after summing, the 0th axis is *removed* so the result is of shape (3,). The 0th axis had length 2, and each sum is composed of adding those 2 elements.  The shape (2,3) "becomes" (3,). You can know the resultant shape in advance! This can help guide your thinking.

To test your understanding, consider `np.sum(arr, axis=1)`. Now the 1-axis is removed. So the resultant shape will be `(2,)`, and element in the result will be the sum of 3 values.

```
In [3]: np.sum(arr, axis=1)
Out[3]: array([ 3, 12])
```

The 3 equals 0+1+2, and the 12 equals 3+4+5.

---

So we see that summing an axis *eliminates* that axis from the result. This has bearing on `np.dot`, since the calculation performed by `np.dot` is a *sum* of products. Since `np.dot` performs a summing operation along certain axes, that axis is removed from the result. That is why applying `np.dot` to  arrays of shape (2,) and (2,2) results in an array of shape (2,). The first 2 in both arrays is summed over, eliminating both, leaving only the second 2 in the second array.

Comment: My problem is exactly the axes idea. I don't understand what does it mean to go through the axes like sum(m, axes=0) or axes=1. Also in your example I think multiplying (2,) * (2,2) should result in (2,2) because you take the dimensnion from the far right and far left. As in ((N,M,M,P)) --- becomes (N,P)

Comment: Thank you so much, but what I'm still missing is visualizing what happens to arr when you eliminate an axis. Suppose you eliminate axis=0 how does the arr look then. Same with axis=1. I'm unable to picture in my mind.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `np.sum(arr, axis=0)` does not affect `arr`. It returns a new array, leaving `arr` untouched. As far as visualization goes, note the part above where I describe things like "5 equals 1+4". Look for the 5 in the result, and the 1 and 4 in `arr`. Do you see how this is summing numbers in the same column?

Comment: That's exactly why I asked. My mind visualized this as being done over rows not columns, because it picks a column and the summation is going downard i.e along the rows. I can't see how this *eliminates* the 0th dimension. I can't understand how it was eliminated or its sense.

Comment: When you see `axis=0`, think `axis 0 correspond to "rows" in 2D`. (We can think about higher dimensions later). This specifies the "direction of motion" for the sums. The iteration is moving down through the rows. Since all the numbers in the same column are being aggregated into one number, the row axis disappears (is eliminated) and all that is left is one number for each column. So the result has one fewer axis. The axis that is eliminated is the axis that represented the rows, that is, the 0 axis. So when you see `axis=0`, the net effect on the shape is that the `0-axis` gets eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

1. `A` is a 2D array, namely a matrix, with its *shape* being (2, 3). From docstring of  `numpy.matrix`:

   > A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature through operations.
2. `numpy.rank` return the number of *dimensions* of an array, which is quite different from the concept of [rank in linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29), e.g. `A` is an array of dimension/rank 2.
3. `np.dot(V, M)`, or `V.dot(M)` multiplies matrix `V` with `M`. Note that numpy.dot do the multiplication as far as possible. **If  V is N:1 and M is N:N**, `V.dot(M)` would raise an `ValueError`.

e.g.:

```
In [125]: a
Out[125]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])

In [126]: b
Out[126]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [1, 2]])

In [127]: a.dot(b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-9a1f5761fa9d> in <module>()
----> 1 a.dot(b)

ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

### EDIT:

**I don't understand the difference between Shape of (N,) and (N,1) and it relates to the dot() documentation.**

`V` of shape (N,) implies an 1D array of length N, whilst shape (N, 1) implies a 2D array with N rows, 1 column:

```
In [2]: V = np.arange(2)

In [3]: V.shape
Out[3]: (2,)

In [4]: Q = V[:, np.newaxis]

In [5]: Q.shape
Out[5]: (2, 1)

In [6]: Q
Out[6]: 
array([[0],
       [1]])
```

As the docstring of `np.dot` says:

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D
>   arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation).

It also performs vector-matrix multiplication if one of the parameters is a vector. Say `V.shape==(2,); M.shape==(2,2)`:

```
In [17]: V
Out[17]: array([0, 1])

In [18]: M
Out[18]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

In [19]: np.dot(V, M)  #treats V as a 1*N 2D array
Out[19]: array([4, 5]) #note the result is a 1D array of shape (2,), not (1, 2)

In [20]: np.dot(M, V)  #treats V as a N*1 2D array
Out[20]: array([3, 5]) #result is still a 1D array of shape (2,), not (2, 1)

In [21]: Q             #a 2D array of shape (2, 1)
Out[21]: 
array([[0],
       [1]])

In [22]: np.dot(M, Q)  #matrix multiplication
Out[22]: 
array([[3],            #gets a result of shape (2, 1)
       [5]])
```

Comment: but if V is a 1D vector, then dot(V, M) still works! I think my confusion is more about V being of shape (N,). I don't understand the difference between Shape of (N,) and (N,1) and it relates to the dot() documentation.