# Difference between numpy.zeros(n) and numpy.zeros(n,1)

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between

`numpy.zeros(n)`

and

`numpy.zeros(n,1)`?

The output for the first statement is

[0 0 ..... n times]

whereas the second one is

([0]
 [0]

.... n rows)

Comment: I get an error with `numpy.zeros(n, 1)`. I'm guessing you meant `numpy.zeros((n,1))`.

Comment: for a detailed description of the difference between `(n,)` shape and `(n,1)` look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r (and other such questions).

Comment: @hpaulj: I'd go as far as saying that's a perfect candidate for a question to close this as a dupe of

Answer (score 3):

The first argument indicates the shape of the array. A scalar argument implies a "flat" array (vector), whereas a tuple argument is interpreted as the dimensions of a tensor. So if the argument is the tuple `(m,n)`, `numpy.zeros` will return a matrix with `m` rows and `n` columns. In your case, it is returning a matrix with `n` rows and `1` column.

Although your two cases are equivalent in some sense, linear algebra routines that require a vector as input will likely expect something like the first form.

Comment: numpy treats 1-D matrices (n,) differently than 2-D matrices with a singleton dimension (n, 1).

Comment: @TWReever: Thanks for clarifying my last statement.

Comment: definitely takes some getting used to, especially if used to the more conventional way they're treated, like in Matlab.

Comment: MATLAB still has fossils from the days when its only data structure was a 2d matrix.  `numpy` lives in world with scalars and lists.  Its arrays can have any number of dimensions - 0,1,2....