# Apply numpy.convolve to 1-dim vectors (two-dimensional arrays with singleton dimension)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to numpy.

I learned the difference between rank-1 array and 1-dim vector from [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

I'm also told to use vector where possible for machine learning tasks instead of rank1 array.
(It's from https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks-deep-learning/lecture/87MUx/a-note-on-python-numpy-vectors at 4:35)

I'm trying to use numpy.convolve and I don't see it takes 1-dim vector.

Is there a way to pass 1-dim vector to `numpy.convolve` or should I use (N,) shape array?

Comment: does singleton also mean simplex?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `numpy.convolve` describes the inputs as "one-dimensional arrays."

There is no separate "vector" in NumPy, only a 1D array.  A higher-dimensional array where all but the first dimensions are 1 is often usable too.

I think you're at the point where you just need to try it and see.  It should work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The input arrays to `numpy.convolve` must be one-dimensional, of shape `(N,)`.

To convolve  arrays with more than one dimension, use [scipy.signal.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html#scipy.signal.convolve)

```
from scipy import signal
a = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1))
b = np.random.normal(size=(5, 1))
signal.convolve(a, b)
```

---

I would seriously question the wisdom of that advice (does it come from someone who works with Matlab more than with NumPy?) but if you must follow it in NumPy  then `squeeze()` the arrays to remove singleton dimension prior to convolution and then `reshape` to restore that dimension

```
a = np.random.normal(size=(10, 1))
b = np.random.normal(size=(5, 1))     
c = np.convolve(a.squeeze(), b.squeeze()).reshape(-1, 1)
```

It looks like pointless waste of time for NumPy but who knows, maybe the benefits of obeying the  Machine Learning Law are worth it.

Comment: I added where I got the advice