# How to append numpy array to numpy array of different size?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning

I have 2 arrays to concatenate:

X_train's shape is `(3072, 50000)`
y_train's shape is `(50000,)`

I'd like to concatenate them so I can shuffle the indices all in one go.  I have tried the following, but neither works:

```
np.concatenate([X_train, np.transpose(y_train)])
np.column_stack([X_train, np.transpose(y_train)])
```

How can I concatenate them?

Comment: Concatenate to what? You got input-dimensions, what output-dimension do you want? (from a ML-perspective i don't see this making sense)

Comment: Can't you just reshape `Y_train` to `(1,50000)`?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, thanks!  Btw, why do I get (50000,) in the first place?  Is that a numpy array?  Seems like it's some kind of vector or list, idk.  I'm new to numpy

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r) might help with the difference between the two

Comment: In `numpy` 1-d arrays are just as useful as 2-d (or higher).

Comment: @DavidG If I could upvote that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r) comment 10 times, I would.  I don't know if I would have known how to find that post without your help.  Perhaps I should add some tags to it to make it easier to dig up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you some recommendation targeting the task, not your problem: **don't do this!**

Assuming `X` are your samples / observations, `y` are your targets:

Just generate a random-permutation and create views (nothing copied or modified) into those, e.g. (untested):

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.random(size=(50000, 3072))
y = np.random.random(size=50000)

perm = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])  # assuming X.shape[0] == y.shape[0]
X_perm = X[perm]  # views!!!
y_perm = y[perm]
```

**Reminder:** your start-shapes are not compatible to most python-based ml-tools as the usual interpretation is:

- first-dim / rows: samples
- second-dim / cols: features

As #samples need to be the same as #target-values `y`, you will see that my example is correct in regards to this, while yours need a transpose on `X`

Answer (score 0):

As DavidG said, I realized the answer is that y_train has shape `(50000,)` so I needed to reshape it before concat-ing

```
np.concatenate([X_train,         
     np.reshape(y_train, (1, 50000))])
```

Still, this evaluated very slowly in Jupyter.  If there's a faster answer, I'd be grateful to have it