# About concatenating two vectors in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector `y` of size `4 x 1` , and another vector `y2` of size `1 x 4`, I need to concatenate the vectors `y` and real and imaginary parts of `y2`.

The problem is that when I reshape the vector `y2` into vector `4 x 1`, and then concatenate it with vector `y`, it gives me an error of `'all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly'` .

Here is the code I made, So `Y3` is expected to be a vector of size `12 x 1`, but the last command gives an error:

```
import numpy as np

h = np.random.randn(4, 4) + 1j * np.random.randn(4, 4)
x = np.array([[1 + 1j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j], [0 + 0j]])
y = h.dot(x)
n = 3
y2 = np.zeros((1, 4), dtype=np.complex)
for ii in range(n):
    y2[: , ii] = np.linalg.pinv(h[: , ii].reshape(-1,1)).dot(x)
y_con = np.concatenate((np.real(y2),np.imag(y2)))
y_m = np.absolute(y)
y_con2 = y_con.reshape(8,1)
Y3 = np.concatenate((y_con2, y_m))
```

Comment: This code runs.  `y_con2` is (8,1), `y_m` is (4,1).  `Y3` is (12,1), concatenated on 0 axis.  `y_con` is (2,4), the result of concatenating two (1,4) arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj , I don't know why does it give me an error of     Y3  = np.concatenate([y_con.reshape(-1,1), y_m])
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: If you used `axis=1` when making `y_con`, the result would be (1,8).  Or you could have started with `y2=np.zeros((4,1)...)`.

Comment: I ran this in an interactive Ipython session, so was able to look at the shape of all the variables. And play around with alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Y3  = np.concatenate([y_con.reshape(-1,1), y_m])
```

y_m is `4 X 1` so reshape y_con to `n X 1` to concatenate row wise

Comment: You mean no need to run this line ? y_con2 = y_con.reshape(8,1) ??

Comment: When I did this, I got a vector of shape (12,1) , however I need a vector of shape (12,) . I don't know what's the difference between them but I think there are difference between them !!

Comment: Just do reshape(-1) to change (12,1) to (12,).  [about the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r) (`Y3 = Y3.reshape(-1)`)