# Numpy.shape behaviour different on 1-D array and 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I've just started using NumPy and I get that this is a very basic and wierd thing to point out but I noticed that the shape function acts differently when called on a 1D array vs when called on a 2D array.

Here's how it returns the results in 1D array -

```
    arr=np.array([1,2,3])
    arr.shape
OUTPUT - (3,)
In this the number of columns is represented before the " , " ie its represented as (columns,)
```

And here's how it returns the results in 2D array -

```
    arr1=np.array([[1,2,3,],[4,5,6]])
    arr1.shape
OUTPUT - (2,3)
In this the number of columns is represented after the " , ".  ie its represented as (rows,columns).
```

This is not something that effects its functionality or its usefulness but I was still wondering why it returns the output in case of a 1D array in that way. Even if the shape is 1D and the number of rows is left blank, why does the number of columns appear before the " , " ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

Comment: The comma is part of python's `tuple` representation.  `shape` is a `tuple`  `numpy` is a python package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the shape of a numpy's array is a tuple. You can see it here:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(type(arr.shape))

# output: <class 'tuple'>
```

And tuples in general are shown like that. Look at the example below:

```
arr = tuple([1])
print(arr)

# output: (1,)
```