# The shape of an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Why the shape of any 1d array has an extra comma? Why **(5,)** instead of **(5)**. 
And why an extra comma is omitted for >= 2 arrays? Why it is **(3,2)** instead of **(3,2,)**.

**1D Example**

```
data = array([11, 22, 33, 44, 55])
print(data.shape)
```

(5,) <======= EXTRA COMMA

**2D Example**

```
data = [[11, 22],
[33, 44],
[55, 66]]
data = array(data)
print(data.shape)
```

(3,2) <====

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

Comment: No. I am not asking the difference between (R,1) and (R). I am asking the shape function internals.

Comment: shape returns _Tuple of array dimensions_. If you try to do `type((5))` and  `type((5, ))` you will see that the former returns `int` and the latter returns `tuple`. In fact to have a tuple with one element you should add an extra comma.

Comment: `type((5))` vs. `type((5,))` vs. `type((5,1))` are all different things. However, using extra comma is a little bit confusing. But it is Ok. I got it. Maybe a better represantation will be found.

Comment: For example: `type((5))` is `int` and `type((5,))`  is `tuple(5)` and `type((5,1))` may `tuple(5,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`(1)` would be more consistent with tuples of length greater than one, but in Python syntax, this is nothing more than an expression in brackets and evaluates to the integer `1`. `(1,)` on the other hand is a `tuple`.

(By the way, you can also write `(1,2,)` instead of `(1,2)`.)