# How can I turn a (680,) singular tuple into a (680,1) pair tuple in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays: `data = (680,)` and `sigma2=(680,1)`.

I need to do `data_s= data/sigma2`, but if I perform like it is, the output is `data_s=(680,680)`, while I need to obtain `data_s=(680,1)`.

I think I have to convert my data one-tuple with size `(680,)` into a pair tuple with size `(680,1)`.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: These are not tuples. If they were you would get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'tuple'` Please, show [mre]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your questions mentions the same values sometimes as "arrays", sometimes as "tuples". Please [edit] your question so that it's clear what data type they are. Also, please mention if you use NumPy here and if so, apply the [tag:numpy] tag. If possible, provide a [mre].

Comment: [This might be of interest.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r/22074424#22074424)

Answer (score 1):

**if you're referring to a shape of a NumPy array, rather than a tuple**

(your provided example does not represent a tuple):

given some array `x` with shape `(680,)`, you can use `x[...,np.newaxis]` to expand it's dimension

---

toy example:

```
x = np.empty((680,))
print(x.shape)
x = x[..., np.newaxis]
print(x.shape)
```

out:

```
(680,)
(680, 1)
```