# What is a numpy array of size = () ? Why does multiplying it by 1 return a numpy int and how are the two different?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

### The issue

I have a very simple function which uses `numpy.where()` for a very simple calculation.

1. If the input is a scalar, the output is a numpy array of size ().
2. If I multiply it by one, it becomes a numpy int32 of the same size.

## My questions are:

what is the difference between 1 and 2?

- Are they both scalars? Does such a thing as a *numpy scalar* even exist?
- Why does multiplying it by one change the type? Is this a known, documented feature/bug?
- why do other numpy functions, e.g. `np.arange(5,6)` return an array of size `(1,)` instead?

I doubt I am the first one to come across this but I haven't found much online.

I have found [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r) on the difference between an array of shape (n,) and one of shape (n,1), but that's a different matter.

### Toy example:

```
import numpy as np

def my_find(a):
    return np.where(a == 0 , 1, 0)

out_scalar = my_find(5)
out_scalar_times_1 = 1 * out_scalar

print("a scalar input return an output of type:")
print(type(out_scalar))
print("and of shape")
print(out_scalar.shape)

print("")
print("Multiplying it by 1 returns a:")
print(type(out_scalar_times_1))

out_array = my_find(np.arange(0,5))
```

### Spyder screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is such a thing as a `numpy` scalar

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html

A numpy array can have 0,1,2 or more dimensions.  There's a lot of overlap between

```
np.int64(3)          # numpy int
np.array(3)          # 0d array
np.array([3])        # 1d array with 1 element
np.int(3)            # python int
3                    # python int
```

The first 3 have array attributes like `shape` and `dtype`.  The differences between the first two are minor.

In a function like `where`, `numpy` first converts the arguments to array, e.g. `np.array(5)`, `np.array(1)`

```
In [161]: np.where(5, 1, 0)
Out[161]: array(1)
In [162]: _.shape
Out[162]: ()
In [163]: np.array(5)
Out[163]: array(5)
```

But math like addition with a scalar may return a numpy scalar:

```
In [164]: np.array(5) + 1
Out[164]: 6
In [165]: type(_)
Out[165]: numpy.int64
In [166]: np.array(5) * 1
Out[166]: 5
In [167]: type(_)
Out[167]: numpy.int64
```

Indexing an array can also produce such a scalar:

```
In [182]: np.arange(3)[1]
Out[182]: 1
In [183]: type(_)
Out[183]: numpy.int64
```

`where` 'broadcasts' the arguments, so the resulting shape is, in the broadcasted sense, the "largest":

```
In [168]: np.where(np.arange(5),1,0)
Out[168]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [173]: np.where(5, [1],0)
Out[173]: array([1])
In [174]: np.where(0, [1],0)
Out[174]: array([0])
In [175]: np.where([[0]], [1],0)
Out[175]: array([[0]])
```

If `spyder` has tab completion like `ipython`, you can get a list of all the methods attached to an object.  The methods for an `np.int64(3)` will look a lot like the those for `np.array(3)`.  But very different from `3`.

There are also arrays with 0 elements - if one of the dimensions is 0

```
Out[184]: array([], dtype=int64)
In [185]: _.shape
Out[185]: (0,)
In [186]: np.arange(1)
Out[186]: array([0])
In [187]: _.shape
Out[187]: (1,)
```

Obviously a 0d can't have 0 elements, because it doesn't have any 0 dimensions.

Indexing a 0d array (or numpy scalar) is a bit tricker (but still logical):

```
In [189]: np.array(3)[()]      # 0 element indexing tuple
Out[189]: 3
In [190]: type(_)
Out[190]: numpy.int64
In [191]: np.array(3).item()
Out[191]: 3
In [192]: type(_)
Out[192]: int
In [193]: np.array(3)[()][()]
Out[193]: 3
```

The return of addition might be explained by 'array_priority'

`dtype` is not preserved in operations like this.  Add a float to an int, and get a float.

```
In [203]: type(np.array(3, np.int16) + 3)
Out[203]: numpy.int64
In [204]: type(np.array(3, np.int16) + 3.0)
Out[204]: numpy.float64
```

### `ufunc` casting

`+` is actually a call to `np.add` ufunc.  `ufunc` take key words like `casting` that give finer control over what results can be:

```
In [214]: np.add(np.array(3, np.int16), 3)
Out[214]: 6
In [215]: np.add(np.array(3, np.int16), 3, casting='no')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-215-631cb3a3b303>", line 1, in <module>
    np.add(np.array(3, np.int16), 3, casting='no')
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' input 0 from dtype('int16') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'no'
    
In [217]: np.add(np.array(3, np.int16), 3, casting='safe')
Out[217]: 6
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#output-type-determination

I was speculating that `__array_priority__` played a role in returning a `np.int64`, but priorities go the wrong way.

```
In [194]: np.array(3).__array_priority__
Out[194]: 0.0
In [195]: np.int64(3).__array_priority__
Out[195]: -1000000.0
In [196]: np.array(3) + np.int64(3)
Out[196]: 6
In [197]: type(_)
Out[197]: numpy.int64
```

I don't know where it's documented, but often an operation will return a `numpy scalar` rather than a 0d array.

I just remembered/discovered one difference between 0d and numpy scalar - mutability

```
In [222]: x
Out[222]: array(3)
In [223]: x[...] = 4
In [224]: x
Out[224]: array(4)
In [225]: x = np.int64(3)
In [226]: x[...] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-226-f7dca2cc5565>", line 1, in <module>
    x[...] = 4
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object does not support item assignment
```

Python classes can share a lot of behaviors/methods, but differ in others.

Comment: Very insightful, thanks. However, I am still not clear on why multiplying it by 1 returns a scalar, effectively changing the data type. Nor why other numpy functions return an array of size (1,)

Comment: Size  1 or `shape` (1,)?  `np.int64(3)`, `np.array(3)`, np.array([3])` all have size 1.