# Confusing type of results of binary arithmetic operations involving Python builtin numeric types and Numpy types float64 and complex128

Tags: python, numpy

Using multiplication operator `mul` for example, code

```
import numpy as np

v = 1.0

a = float(v)
b = np.float64(v)

print(type(a*b), type(a.__mul__(b)))

a = complex(v)
b = np.complex128(v)
print(type(a*b), type(a.__mul__(b)))
```

produce the following output

```
<class 'numpy.float64'> <class 'float'>
<class 'numpy.complex128'> <class 'complex'>
```

Since `<class 'float'>.__mul__(<class 'numpy.float64'>)` and `<class 'complex'>.__mul__(<class 'numpy.complex128'>)` do not in fact return `NotImplemented`, according to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) results should be `<class 'float'>` and `<class 'complex'>`, respectively.

Why is it not so? It seems binary arithmetic operators (+,-,*,/,etc) for builtin numeric types behave differently than their corresponding `__op__()` functions?

Comment: check `b.__rmul__(a)`

Comment: `b.__rmul__(a)` is correct in both cases. The question is why `a.__mul__(b)` is ignored when it **does not** return `NotImplemented`.

Comment: `numpy` objects have a higher priority., and control the form of the '*'

Comment: what is this priority? I can't seem to find anything about this in Python documentation.

Comment: I don't recall where I read about this priority, probably in some other SO.  Here's a some what related question, dealing with the distinction between a 0d array and numpy 'scalar', https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66169279/what-is-a-numpy-array-of-size-why-does-multiplying-it-by-1-return-a-numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong about the `priority`.  There is a priority value that controls how `ndarray` and its subclasses interact, but with the Python numbers it may be just a matter of `NotImplemented`, or subclassing

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

```
Note If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type 
and that subclass provides a different implementation of the reflected 
method for the operation, this method will be called before the left 
operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to 
override their ancestors’ operations.
```

With your example:

```
In [107]: a = 1.0; b = np.float64(1.0)
In [108]: type(a*b)
Out[108]: numpy.float64
In [109]: type(a.__mul__(b))
Out[109]: float
In [110]: type(b.__rmul__(a))
Out[110]: numpy.float64
In [111]: type(b).__mro__
Out[111]: 
(numpy.float64,
 numpy.floating,
 numpy.inexact,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 float,
 object)
```

`b` controls `a*b` because `type(b)` is a subclass of `type(a)`.  `b.__rmul__` is used.

`np.complex128` is also a subclass of `complex`.

With integers, `not implemented` is the factor

```
In [113]: c = 1; d = np.int64(1)
In [114]: type(c*d)
Out[114]: numpy.int64
In [115]: c.__mul__(d)
Out[115]: NotImplemented
In [116]: d.__rmul__(c)
Out[116]: 1
In [117]: type(_)
Out[117]: numpy.int64
In [118]: type(d).__mro__
Out[118]: 
(numpy.int64,
 numpy.signedinteger,
 numpy.integer,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 object)
```

`np.int64` is not a subclass of `int`.