# How does python choose between __mul__ and __rmul__

Tags: python, numpy, overloading

In the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__rmul__#object.__rmul__), it is said that `__mul__` will be firstly called to implement the binary arithmetic operations `*`. `__rmul__` will not be called unless `__mul__` is not supported or the right operand is subclass of the left operand. However, for the following code:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = np.array(2)

print("a * b:", a * b)
print("a.__mul__(b):", a.__mul__(b))
print("b.__rmul__(a):", b.__rmul__(a))
```

My first thought was that the result of `a * b` should be `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`, just identical to `a * 2`. However, the actual output is:

```
a * b: [2 4 6]
a.__mul__(b): [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
b.__rmul__(a): [2 4 6]
```

It seems that `a * b` calls `b.__rmul__(a)`. However, in this case, `a.__mul__(b)` is implemented and gives the expected result, and `np.ndarray` is apparently not the subclass of `list`.

So, my question is, what is really going on in this example, and how does python choose between the binary arithmetic operations and their reflected operands?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), something more interesting is found from the following code:

```
import numpy as np

class Foo1(list):
    pass

class Foo2(list):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        print('in Foo2.__mul__')
        return super().__mul__(other)

print('Foo1:')
print(Foo1([1, 2, 3]) * np.array(3))
print('Foo2:')
print(Foo2([1, 2, 3]) * np.array(3))
```

The output is:

```
Foo1:
[3 6 9]
Foo2:
in Foo2.__mul__
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

As both `Foo1` and `Foo2` inherit from `list`, the only difference is `Foo2` overwrites `__mul__`, and explicitly calls `super().__mul__`. But the `Foo1` and `Foo2` give totally different result! So, as [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) said, there should be some sort of special relation between `list` and `np.ndarray`. However, it really seems weird as `np.ndarray` comes from a third-party library and there should be no way it can modify the behavior of builtin types.

Comment: In my experience, a numpy array has 'control' of such an operation, converting the list to array.  I recall digging into the hows and whys not long ago, but forget the details.

Comment: This is what I was remembering, but not sure if it explains your case, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68302275/901925

Comment: `[1,2,3]*np.int32(3)` does replicate.  `[1,2,3]*np.array([1,2])` gives a broadcasting error, (3,) shape with (2,).  Other SO that explore [numpy] and `__mul__` or `__rmul__` do so in the context of a custom dtype.  It may be hard, working just from docs and example, to determine exactly why the array controls this operation.

Comment: When I make a class that inherits from list, the `Foo([1,2,3])*np.array(3)` behaves a you expect.  So there must be some sort special relation between `list` and `ndarray` that doesn't carry over to user defined classes.  I expect it's implemented within `numpy`, but I don't know how it relates to the interpreter's use of `__rmul__` and `__mul__`.

Comment: @hpaulj The answer from [stackoverflow.com/q/68302275/901925](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68302275/901925) is really helpful. In that case, the right oprand's type is subclass of the left oprand's type. But in this case, `np.ndarray` is not `list`'s subclass. So, there might be some other reason's for this problem.

Comment: I suspect that list objects do not *really* implement `__mul__` — notice how sequence repetition is special-cased in [PyNumber_Multiply](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/245f1f260577a005fd631144b4377febef0b47ed/Objects/abstract.c#L1107), and that the ["as-number methods"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/245f1f260577a005fd631144b4377febef0b47ed/Objects/listobject.c#L3052) of the list type is NULL. Obviously, this does not explain why lists apparently have a `__mul__` method...