# Why does numpy array could have shape without column number?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

[image]

What does ***(13, )*** mean here? without column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

Comment: It's the same as `(5, 1)`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r) for more details.

Comment: @user17242583, when `broadcasting` a (5,) behaves more like a (1,5) than a (5,1).